# Setting Excerpt Length for WooCommerce Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set the excerpt length for WooCommerce products but the following code does not work as expected:

```
<?php
    function custom_excerpt_length($length) {
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_type == 'post')
            return 10;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'product')
            return 10;
        else if ($post->post_type == 'product_variation')
            return 10;
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `woocommerce/templates/single-product/short-description.php` folder there is the following code.

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```

Replace the above code with the following code*.

```
<?php $excerpt = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
    echo substr($length,0, 10);
?>
```

Changing 10, with a length you require.

It is advised to copy that file to `yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/short-description.php`, otherwise when/if you update woocommerce your changes will be overwritten.